# Run google analytics locally

Tags: google-analytics

I want to test google analytics with google tag manager locally

I have

```
operation system: windows
wampserver
gmail account
```

Is there any guide how can I configure a simple html page I have in wampserver with google analytics and run it locally and possible integrate it with google tag manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already have a [GTM account and access to it](https://tagmanager.google.com) and a GA account with its tracking (UA-) Id, the first thing you want to do is drop that GTM snippet after the opening  tag. The GTM snippet can be found by:

1. Selecting your container.
2. Going to "Admin" in the top menu.
3. Going to "Install Google Tag Manager"

The next thing to do is create a Google Analytics tag in GTM and ensure that it is prepared for working locally (using localhost).

You can create the GA tag by:

1. navigating to your container first.
2. Under "Choose Product", selecting your GA flavor.
3. Under "configure tag", adding your GA UA Id.
4. **important:** Go to "More settings" -> "Fields to set" -> and add "cookieDomain" for the field, and "none" for the value.
5. Select "All Pages" for the Trigger.
6. Publish the tag.

Comment: You can get to the debugger in two ways: 1.) Going to your GTM container and clicking on the arrow next to Publish, then "Preview and Debug" 2.) going to the "Versions" navigation item in your GTM container. Find your last published container and clicking on "Share Preview" and copy and pasting that url in the browser you have open.